# solr EdgeNGram slow query time

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a 4.4 solr core for postal address searching, that I configured after reading [this solr name search approach](http://java.dzone.com/articles/tips-name-search-solr).

Now everything is fine except for query time. I have around ~80M indexed addresses, and am search a set of 800K venues. When using another approach to this problem with PortugueseStemFactory, all 800K searches would finish in about 5 hours.

This EdgeNGramFactory approach is taking well over 24 hours now and have just passed 10% of the whole file. It's more precise, but takes too long to batchjob.

I really need some advice about how to improve query time for this particular case, or even overall tuning and bottleneck investigation and troubleshooting tips for Solr.

Also in my query I'm using sort by strdist and sqedist, if that is of any relevance to this problem.

If you need more details please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In general solr query search performance can be optimized using the [Search optimization](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed).

Given the size of the size of your index, it is better to [shard](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) it to improve the performance. Also i have seen having enough physical RAM on the box help speed up the search operation.

Also, i would suggest use debugQuery=true in your solr query, so that you see the breakup of which part/component is taking time.

strdist is bit intense activity, but it really depends on the size of the response from the search results. But i don't necessarily think that this causes the problem.